# Convert Json object into custom Object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a massive json file that i am parsing. But I have a problem when parsing it.
There is a field in the file that looks similar:

```
"pageTitle": {
"en": "Some content here...."
},
```

I store this as a dictionary:

```
[JsonProperty("pageTitle")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> PageTitle { get; set; }
```

But sometimes this field is empty, and when it is the Json.Net method

```
ToObject<MyCustomClass>()
```

Fails when trying to convert pageTitle because it appears to be an empty array and not an object. Is there a JsonPropery to make it ignore this empty array and just carry on?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to ignore the `null` values, then it is possible to decorate the property as follows:

```
[JsonProperty("pageTitle", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
```

If the JSON string being parsed is an empty array [] or an invalid input, you might have to write a custom converter by extending the abstract class, JsonConverter or extending one of the inbuilt converters in [Newtonsoft.Json.Converters](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/N_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters.htm) and invoke it as:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyCustomClass>(jsonString, new CustomConverter());
```

**OR**

Handle the exception that happens during deserialization as follows:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyCustomClass>(json, new 
                        JsonSerializerSettings
                        {
                          Error = HandleError
                        });
```

Handler:

```
private static void HandleError(object sender, ErrorEventArgs e)
  {
       // Get the error message using 'e.ErrorContext.Error.Message'
       // e.ErrorContext.OriginalObject will give you the object/property that failed to deserialze
       e.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
  }
```